# embedded variable that doesn't work like i want

Tags: php

I'm not very able with PHP.

I have this code:

```
<?php
    $sq1053= "Liverpool";
    $query5 = "SELECT ruolo1, nazionalita, cognome, nome, squadra, stipendio, scadenza FROM giocatori WHERE club='$clubscelto'";
    $result = $con->query($query5);
    $array24 = [];
    while($row24 = $result->fetch_row()){
        array_push($array24, $row24);
        for($nuovariga = 0; $nuovariga < $tesserati; $nuovariga++)
        {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:10%;border: 1px solid black"><b><?php echo $array24[$nuovariga][0]; ?></b></td>
            <td style="width:50%;border: 1px solid black"><b><?php echo $$array24[$nuovariga][1] . $array24[$nuovariga][2] . $array24[$nuovariga][3]; ?></b></td>
            <td style="width:10%;border: 1px solid black"><b><?php echo '$sq' . ($array24[$nuovariga][4]); ?></b></td>
            <td style="width:20%;border: 1px solid black"><b><?php echo $array24[$nuovariga][5]; ?></b></td>
            <td style="width:10%;border: 1px solid black"><b><?php echo $array24[$nuovariga][6]; ?></b></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table></br>
```

My Array provides to give me many variables like $sq1053 called in the main part of the code, but this variable doesn't work as I want. When I print all on my page I see "$sq1053" and not "Liverpool". How may I obtain a working variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you're trying to do, replace:

```
<?php echo '$sq' . ($array24[$nuovariga][4]); ?>
```

with:

```
<?php echo ${'sq' . $array24[$nuovariga][4]}; ?>
```

See [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) from the manual.

That being said, I would strongly suggest making use of [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) instead.